# Error Help: Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a005e'

Tags: vbscript

I'm getting the following error on this page for Standard Advert Listings (scroll down to the bottom): http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/fitness-sport-and-leisure/days-out.html

This used to work fine without the error, so I can't see why all of a sudden it's throwing the error.

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a005e' Invalid use of Null:
>   'Replace' /PageObjects/DirectoryBrowser/i_DirectoryAdvert.asp, line
>   124

The code at line 124 is:

```
strDB_AdvertItem = Replace(strDB_AdvertItem, "[OpeningTimes]", rsDB_Ads("OpeningTimes"))
```

Any ideas as to why this could be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the error either `strDB_AdvertItem` or `rsDB_Ads("OpeningTimes")` has a value of null.

I suspect it will be `rsDB_Ads("OpeningTimes")` which may have had a valid value in the database last time you ran the program but doesn't any more.

Something like the code below (not tested) should prevent the error occurring, but you'll need to check that the NULLs aren't causing unexpected behaviour elsewhere

```
Dim OpeningTimes
If IsNull(rsDB_Ads("OpeningTimes")) Then OpeningTimes = "" Else OpeningTimes = rsDB_Ads("OpeningTimes")
If IsNull(strDB_AdvertItem) Then strDB_AdvertItem = ""

strDB_AdvertItem = Replace(strDB_AdvertItem, "[OpeningTimes]", OpeningTimes)
```